# Firewall configuration parser extraneous input

Tags: antlr, antlr4

I'm attempting to write a configuration parser for some firewall equipments. I'm using ANTLR for the first time.

What I want to parse is typically the following sort of text :

```
config wireless-controller global
    set name ''
    set location ''
    set max-retransmit 3
    set data-ethernet-II disable
    set link-aggregation disable
    set mesh-eth-type 8755
    set fiapp-eth-type 5252
    set discovery-mc-addr 221.0.4.254
    set max-clients 0
    set rogue-scan-mac-adjacency 6
    set ipsec-base-ip 172.252.0.4
    set wtp-share disable
    set ap-log-server disable
    set ap-log-server-ip 0.0.0.0
    set ap-log-server-port 0
end
```

The input data is "config" blocks with configuration lines. I already came up with these rules :

```
   1   │ grammar Fortigate ;
   2   │ 
   3   │ /*
   4   │  * Tokens
   5   │ */
   6   │ 
   7   │ WHITESPACE  : (' ' | '\t')+ -> skip ;
   8   │ NEWLINE     : ('\r'? '\n' | '\n' | '\r')+ ;
   9   │ WORD        : ([a-zA-Z0-9] | '.' | [\-_'"])+ ;
  10   │ ENDBLOCK    : 'end' ;
  11   │ EDITSTART   : 'edit' ;
  12   │ NEXTEDIT    : 'next' ;
  13   │ /*
  14   │  * Parser rules
  15   │ */
  16   │ configline  : ('set'|'unset') WORD+ NEWLINE ;
  17   │ startconfigblock  : 'config' WORD+ NEWLINE ;
  18   │ editline    : EDITSTART '"'.+?'"' ;
  19   │ editblock   : editline configline+ NEXTEDIT NEWLINE ;
  20   │ configblock : startconfigblock (editblock | configline)+ ENDBLOCK NEWLINE;
  21   │ 
  22   │ startRule   : configblock+ ;
```

I still have issues as antlr doesnt seem to like then ending "end\n" of the data to parse :
`line 12:0 extraneous input 'end' expecting {'set', 'unset', 'end', 'edit'}`

However I have quite clean token tree
[image: antlr4 Fortigate startRule -gui]

Antlr doesnt like the ending 'end' text though its in the `configblock` rule, and its not consumed by another rule ...

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The input `end` is being tokenised as a `WORD`. This is because when the lexer can match the same characters for multiple rules, the one defined first "wins". The solution, move the keywords above your `WORD` rule:

```
ENDBLOCK    : 'end' ;
EDITSTART   : 'edit' ;
NEXTEDIT    : 'next' ;
WORD        : ([a-zA-Z0-9] | '.' | [\-_'"])+ ;
```

If you ever want to match `end` also as a `WORD`, then introduce a parser rule like this:

```
word
 : WORD
 | END
 ;
```

and use this `word` in your parser rules instead of `WORD`.

BTW, `([a-zA-Z0-9] | '.' | [\-_'"])+` can be rewritten as `[a-zA-Z0-9.\-_'"]+` and `(' ' | '\t')+` as `[ \t]+`.

And finally, it is always a good idea to "anchor" the start rule of your parser with the `EOF` token: that way you're forcing the parser to consume the entire token stream and not stop halfway.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, that's what I needed. I didnt thought about a word beeing 'end', I need to distinguish 'end' in a config line and end alone in a line as an 'endblock' token. Thank you !